# Issues on using Plots package in Julia

Tags: julia, package, ijulia-notebook, plots.jl

I'm trying to use Plots package in Julia but I get an error message I don't fully understand. Using a Jupyter notebook I followed the canonic way to install and use the package with:

```
Pkg.add("Plots")
using Plots
```

But after then I got this error message:

```
INFO: Precompiling module Plots.
WARNING: Module Compat with uuid 131681569370755 is missing from the cache.
This may mean module Compat does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
ERROR: LoadError: Declaring __precompile__(false) is not allowed in files that are being precompiled.
Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:455
 [2] require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:405
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [5] anonymous at .\<missing>:2
while loading C:\Users\Alex\.julia\v0.6\StaticArrays\src\StaticArrays.jl, in expression starting on line 17
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile StaticArrays to C:\Users\Alex\.julia\lib\v0.6\StaticArrays.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at .\loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:463
 [3] require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:405
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [6] anonymous at .\<missing>:2
while loading C:\Users\Alex\.julia\v0.6\Plots\src\Plots.jl, in expression starting on line 7

Failed to precompile Plots to C:\Users\Alex\.julia\lib\v0.6\Plots.ji.

Stacktrace:
[1] compilecache(::String) at .\loading.jl:710
[2] _require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:497
[3] require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:405
[4] include_string(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:522
```

Could somebody please help me to understand this error and what can I do to fix it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can see in the first line [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl/blob/master/src/Compat.jl) that `Compat` definitely does support precompilation, so first try `Pkg.rm("Compat") ; Pkg.update() ; Pkg.add("Compat")`. Also probably worth adding the output of `Pkg.status()` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you already had Compat in your scope before trying to update. It then has an issue of trying to precompile using a new version of Compat while an old one is still in scope. To fix this, just restart Julia and do `using Plots`.

Comment: When you say "Restart Julia" you mean close and begin a new session or there's a special command to do that task?

Comment: Begin a new session.